# Find mean from geometric PGF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that PGF of type 0 geometric random variable is G = p/(1-z*s)
Now, if I want to find mean, E[X] = d/dz (G) @z=1 = p*s/(1-s*z)^2 but according to wikipedia, mean = (1-p)/p and it does not have s
How do I find mean from PGF?

Comment: There are two different definitions of geometric random variables. The mean is $\frac 1p$ for one definition and $\frac 1p-1 = \frac{1-p}{p}$ for the other. Which one has probability generating function $$G(z) = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)z} = p +p(1-p)z + p(1-p)^2z^2 + \cdots?$$

Comment: You're answer's fine since computing G'(1) gives $\frac {p*(1-p)}{p^2}$ = $\frac {1-p}{p}$